# Swift - Push CollectionView in the background

Tags: ios, swift, layer

How can I push my collectionView in the background programmatically? Right now it covers my bottom-bar. It's easy in Storyboard but I have no idea how do get it done programmatically.

[image]

```
    let theCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let v = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.backgroundColor = .white
    v.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always
    v.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    return v
}()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
self.view.sendSubviewToBack(_ with: UIView)
```

method if I got right your problem and there's another view in back of the collection view.

So for example your view has a view of the `DashboardController` etc. So in block that you wish you must

```
self.view.sendSubviewToBack(theCollectionView)
```

I hope it helps.

There's some to-do to achieve this.

You can hide your collectionView

```
yourCollectionView.isHidden = true
```

You can remove your `UICollectionView` from `superview`

```
   yourCollectionView.removeFromSuperView()
```

Or you can make your `UICollectionView` as `Optional`.

Then you can `removeFromSuperView` and set `nil`.

```
yourCollectionView.removeFromSuperView()
yourCollectionView = nil
```

Then you can set `nil` and `removeFromSuperView`

When you use again, so must init again.

Comment: where do I have to set this up? Inside ViewDidLoad?

Comment: place it to where you use it, is it activated with button click?

Comment: so I tried `self.view.sendSubviewToBack(theCollectionView)` inside viewDidLoad but now it just disappeard

Comment: the problem was that is was behind my background image. I fixed that and now it works! Thanks!

Comment: just a hint: use, `self.view.bringSubviewToFront()` when you want to do opposite of this process :)